# Как получить дату в ISO формате?

Tags: javascript, datetime

Подскажите, как переформанировать дату публикации получаемую с сервера в ISO формат

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const articles = [
    "date": '2016-08-02T15:44:09-05:00',
  ]
  console.log("Date = " + (new Date(article.date)).toDateString());
}
```

Мне необходим формат 2016-08-02 для дальнейшего его установление в тег 
 2016-08-02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так:

```
new Date('2016-08-02T15:44:09-05:00').toISOString(); // 2016-08-02T20:44:09.000Z
```